# iOS: Best approach for image gallery [Image Caching]

Tags: ios, performance, caching, uiimageview, image-gallery

I have to implement an Image Gallery for the iPhone iOS. Pictures are loaded from the web based on an XML document which contains the URLs of the pictures. My question is - what is the best approach for implementing an Image Gallery Overview of all pictures of a certain gallery? (where all pictures are presented to the user at once, like in a GridView. This question focuses on performance issues because one gallery can have more than 100 photos - each of them has a size of 100KB or more).

I already tried to implement a simple View which consists of multiple UIImageViews (rows and cols) where the images are loaded asynchronously. But the App crashes with low memory warnings, so I have to load the pictures on demand and not all at once.

What would be the best way to implement such a Gallery Overview? Using an UITableView with 3 pictures for each cell for instance? Or is it better to use a paged UIScrollView where the user is able to switch between pages where each page presents 12 pictures or so?

The main problem is the caching of the images. Would be glad for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cache images regardless on which solution you do, to cache the images you can either implement your own caching mechanism or use one already mad ( i opt for the second choice) i normally use ASIHTTPRequest, more specifically i use [ASIDownloadCache](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_a_download_cache) check their documentation but its very easy to use

Comment: so this makes it possible to cache a high amount of pictures loaded from the web without receiving memory warnings? (or to deal with high memory usage). My issue isn't related to keep the amount of http requests at a minimum but to cache a high amount of pictures.

Comment: This will give you a way to quickly access downloaded images, what you need to do is to remove the image when its not on screen and then reload it again from the cache, what this solution gives you, is fast realoading of images since its cached

Comment: now i just have to figure out how to determine if an image is on the screen or not. it would be easy for a single image view - but how is this done when I use a grid view to show a couple of images at once?

Comment: you could use removeFromSuperView in your custom class, implement the function and manually remove all images